# Compare elements in each position of an array

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two arrays

```
a = [ab,bc,cd]
b = [bc,ab,cd]
```

I want to compare each element of a with each element of b and then increase `counter += 1` if they match, else `counter -1` and display `counter`

```
counter=0
for i in a:
 for j in b: 
   if a[i-1] == b[j-1]:
      counter = counter + 1
   elif a[i-1] != b[j-1]:
      counter = counter - 1
  print counter
```

I am getting weird results, I am new to programming and help is appreciated.

Sorry for copy paste error

Comment: You're testing the same condition twice.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to get as output for your example list? Assuming list has strings

Comment: Doing `for i in a` iterates over the **members**, not **indices** of `a`. This means that, at each iteration of the loop, `i` will be one of the values stored in the list `a` (`ab`, then `bc` and then `cd`). Try comparing `i` to `j` directly.

Comment: Are they always the same length?

Comment: Also why are you subtracting 1 from each value?

Comment: no they are not same length always my main goal is to find if total edits in 2 arrays is not more than 1. can you please guide me with that?

Answer (score 2):

Your `elif` condition is the same as your `if`, which is probably why it's not working for you. In fact, you don't even need a condition there; it should just be an `else` since you want to catch everything that didn't match the `if`.

That said, this way is much nicer:

```
from itertools import product
counter = sum(1 if x==y else -1 for x, y in product(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sets:

```
a = ['ab','bc','cd']
b = ['bc','ab','cd']

print(len(set(a).intersection(set(b))))

3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['ab','bc','cd']
b = ['bc','ab','cd']

counter = 0
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i == j:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter -= 1
print counter
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a short and fast alternative:

```
sum(2*b.count(x) - len(b) for x in a)
```